# Upload multiple images to server with part params using axio react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, image-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images to server using axio with multiple params as request body. Basically below is the request in native android which am trying to do it in react native.

```
@Headers(HTTPService.NEEDS_AUTH_HEADER)
        @Multipart
        @POST("/api/post")
        Call<Post> create(
                @Part("title") RequestBody title,
                @Part("content") RequestBody content,
                @Part("location") RequestBody location,
                @Part("category") RequestBody category,
                @Part("captions") List<RequestBody> captions,
                @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> parts
        );
```

and this is how am trying to do in react :

```
const config = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'NEEDS_AUTH': true,
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': undefined

      },
      formDataArray,
      url: PATH_API_CREATE_POST,
      data: {
        title: postTitle,
        content: postContent,
        location: locationId,
        category: categoryId,

      }
    }

    axios(config).then(res => console.log('create post ', res)).catch(err => console.log('create post err', err.response))
```

Here it's formDataArray :

`photos.forEach(element => {
      let formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("upload", { uri: element, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpg' })
      formDataArray.push(formdata)
    });`

Unfortunately no images are uploaded to server.

Comment: Change your axios config `'Content-type': undefined` to `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

Comment: now it says `"content-type missing boundary`

Comment: that's why i passed in undefined

Comment: How did you populate `formDataArray`? Let me see.

Comment: updated question

Comment: Just use 1 formData, not an array of formData to achieve that.
For an array form input like `parts`, use `parts[]` as formData key. Like this:
`formData.append("parts[]", partValue);`

So, you just need 1 formData object per axios request.

Comment: You can loop through all `parts` value to append it to formData with the same key, like this: `for (...) formData.append("parts[]", partValue[i]);`

Comment: actually formdata is passed as config , that itself is wrong. i need to pass `title` `content` as well with formdata. do you mean only one instance of formdata needs to be created?

Comment: Yes, just append more data with that instance too, `formData.append("title", title)`, `formData.append("content", content)`.

Comment: not working  `photos.forEach(element => {
      formdata.append("parts[]", { uri: element, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpg' })
      formdata.append('title', postTitle)
      formdata.append('content', postContent)
      formdata.append('location', locationId)
      formdata.append('category', categoryId)
      formDataArray.push(formdata)

    });`

Comment: `photos.forEach(element => { formdata.append("parts[]", { uri: element, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpg' }) }); formdata.append('title', postTitle); formdata.append('content', postContent); formdata.append('location', locationId); formdata.append('category', categoryId);` and then do axios post with `formdata`, not formDataArray anymore.

Comment: this is the response https://imgur.com/a/WWH4zUH

Comment: only one image is sent to server

Comment: it worked , had to use different key for image

Comment: If you are uploading bunch of images then you may need to use queue, otherwise you will never knows if there was any error during uploading and you may need to restart from scratch again for all files. I have faced same issue and finally I switch to native code of iOS for queue and uploading multiple images with progress. Here you will get code how to accomplish this : https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-upload-images-queue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your `photos` array contains an array of file system paths of the uploaded photos,
Your FormData should be looped through like this:

```
const data = new FormData()

photos.forEach((element, i) => {
  const newFile = {
    uri: element, type: 'image/jpg'
  }
  data.append('files', newFile)
});
```

Then you can attach this variable `data` to your post request to upload the array of files to server.

Comment: only one file is getting uploaded though photos are 2.

Comment: it worked. had to use different key when appending new file

Comment: It shouldn't need to use different keys, it should work if you append multiple files to a same `FormData` key

Comment: @Vivek_Neel how did you solve this? my `data` has 2 arrays but when i try to echo in backend php it only shows 1 object

Comment: @Vivek_Neel In that case you need to have 2 instances of FormData for 2 arrays of images

Answer (score 2):

```
const data = new FormData()

photos.forEach((element, i) => {
  const newFile = {
    uri: element, type: 'image/jpg'
  }
  data.append('files[]', newFile)
});
```

docs say https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example